# How to access to a specific tensor row?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

how to extract specific rows in tensor? I'm a little confused.

for example, let's say we want to have row 17
[specified row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk4Sa.png)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed = 5)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3,4,5))
a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you can do:

```
a[1][1][0]
```

or `a[1,1,0]`

Another idea is to reshape your array and select row 17:

```
select_row = 17
a.reshape(int(len(a.flatten())/5),5)[select_row-1]
```

> Output: array([8, 1, 6, 3, 4])

Comment: Hi @Marios,  Is it possible to do this by something like a[:,:,:,:] , I mean why when I write a[:1,:3,:1:5] I don't get the same result?

Comment: Never use chained indexing.  It creates many intermediate views, which is inefficient

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for the info ! Is the reshaping solution better ?